# How to convert json string value into an ArrayList and display the values in Android ListView

Tags: android, json

This is my JSON Array and Object.

```
{
"table1": [
    {
        "item_id": "1",
        "items": [
            "Veg Snacker",
            "Chicken Snacker",
            "Snack Box *1pc. Chicken & Fries",
            "Chicken Rizo",
            "Veg Stripes",
            "Popcorn Chicken"
        ]
    }
],
"success": 1
}
```

So, I want to display this `items` String Value into android `ListView`. I tried allot but I can't get it. so please if anyone know how to convert  `json` string value into an `ArrayList`.

I want Output like:

```
Veg Snacker
Chicken Snacker
Snack Box..... ect,
```

Answer (score 0):

**This should get you started:**

```
 String jsonString = "PUT JSON STRING HERE";
    JsonObject object = new JsonObject(jsonString);
    JsonArray tables = object.getJsonArray("table1");
    for(JsonObject value: tables){

        JsonArray items = value.getJsonArray("items");
        for(JsonObject item: items){
            Log.i("TAG",item.toString());
        }

    }
```

Keep in mind this solution does not have any error handling. I also have not tested this, I just quickly wrote it.